# TurnBasedMatc get a match via an Id

Tags: google-play-services

I'm wondering if its possible to get a TurnBasedMatch if you pass a the TurnBasedMatch Id to a method. I can't find any solutions in the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define this class.

```
    class LoadTurnBasedMatchCallback implements ResultCallback<LoadMatchResult> {

        @Override
        public void onResult(LoadMatchResult res) {
            TurnBasedMatch myMatch = res.getMatch();
        }

    }
```

Now load your match as follows, and when the match is loaded you will receive a call to `onResult` above in which you can obtain your **TurnBasedMatch** from the **ID** you provided.

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.loadMatch(yourApiClient, yourTurnBasedMatchId).setResultCallback(new LoadTurnBasedMatchCallback());
```